# In mapbox, how do you change your location's annotation icon?

Tags: android, mapbox

I know I can set the icon of other annotations / markers using:

```
 new MarkerOptions().icon(myIcon)
```

My question for you is how do I modify my location marker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IconFactory`:

```
IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(<activity context>);
new MarkerOptions().icon(iconFactory.fromResource(<drawable resource>));
```

Or you can customize bitmap icon while adding icon into `Marker` by using `IconFactory.recreate()` method, example scaled bitmap:

```
Icon icon    = iconFactory.fromResource(<drawable resource>);
Icon newIcon = IconFactory.recreate(icon.getId(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon.getBitmap(), 35, 35, false));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the API, in an example, you can use this code

```
mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(41.885, -87.679)));
```

The marker will be at the specified coordinates

Here is the link for further reference

https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/#drawing-a-marker